# Can i open an Xcode project on a button click from another project without custom URL schema?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I want to integrate two Xcode projects together and they both are full Xcode projects with UI and all. For example lets say i have an App 'A' which has a UIButton and on click it should open App 'B' which has its own UI. 
I know we can open an App from another App through Custom URL schema but is there a way i can do this without custom URL schema and via connecting Xcode projects.

I know this a little vague question but i don't a better way to put this.

Thanks,

Comment: When you talk about "Xcode projects" do you actually mean "iOS apps installed on a device"?

Answer (score 0):

You're question doesn't make any sense. You're talking about two very different things. Yes, you may import one Xcode project into another Xcode project and setup a dependency between them. However, this in no way affects how the apps work with each other. If you're wanting to embed one app inside another, you have to do it at the view controller/code level. You cannot simply add one project to another and expect the two to intercommunicate. You'll have to move the functionality of one app to another. Apps are sandboxed on the device and can therefore have no communication with each other except for by using custom URL schemes as you've mentioned.